# Access fields wrapped inside anonymous type or Object class

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a method which returns as follows,

```
return new { a, b, c, d};
```

And method definition is  `public object GetValues();` 
How do I access those variables a, b, c, d after calling this method?

Comment: I've re-opened the Q&A. The other Q&A wasn't about of how to work with returned from a method anonymous objects ........

Answer (score 7):

Two options:

- Use dynamic typing, so long as you're using it from the same assembly:

  ```
  dynamic values = GetValues();
  var a = values.a; //etc
  ```
- Use reflection directly; the generated type will have public read-only properties called `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`

Alternatively, if you can *possibly* change the method to not use an anonymous type, do so. (You may not be able to change the signature of the method depending on the context, but even then you could still cast in the calling code.)

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Well, that's an option for the bigger picture, yes. Will edit.

Answer (score 4):

If you assign it to a `dynamic` you can get the properties out (read on, don't use this code):

```
dynamic d = YourMethodReturningAnonymousType();

var a = d.a;
```

Note you are losing type safety, one of the key aspects of a type safe language like C#. My advice: **never ever use anonymous types across the boundaries of a method**. Create a class instead and pass that out.

Comment: You were just seconds earlier than me, so that doesn't really count. Plus I gave something to work with. Jon missed one crucial step in my opinion, so that would count for me. Not really sure why you care so much about that...

Comment: Who knows, I just gave you an opinion

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this, since you've to return the anonymous object typed as `object` (i.e. `System.Object`).

Options:

- Design a class.
- Return a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` (*best choice if you want to return an unknown number of parameters depending on some given conditions*). For example: `new Dictionary { { "a", 1 }, { "b", 2 } };
- Return a [tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx). Same as `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` advise, but you've lost the chance to give names to each returned value as tuple items are `Item1`, `ItemN`. For example: `Tuple.Create(1, 2);`
- Type as dynamic (*worst option, don't use `dynamic` to avoid typing your references since C# is a strongly-typed language*).

Answer (score 1):

you can use dynamic or reflection

```
dynamic obj=GetValues();
var  a=obj.a;
```

or

```
object obj=GetValues();
var val_a=obj.GetType().GetProperty("a").GetValue(obj, null);
```